# Add headers to several files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have three different .txt files, and in each one of them, I would like to add a different header. For example: `line1="rain", add line to file 1;line2="cap", add line to file 2;line3="different", add line to file 3;`

I tried writing a function `writing_to_files`, that could make it easier, however I'm in doubt on how I can add the content of the lines.

```
def writing_to_files(filename, header_names):
    '''recovers file and writes a line in the file'''
    with file(filename, 'r') as original:
        data=original.read()
        with file(filename, 'w') as modified:
            modified.write(header_names + "\n" + data)
    return True
```

Comment: You should elaborate a bit on your examples. If you show what the files look like before and (should look like) after your function it would be easier to understand what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: What about the above function doesn’t work?

Comment: the above function gives me an error when i try to add a list of the headers.